# Possible to add navigation property to a table-valued function's model in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 with Visual Studio 2015, database-first.

I would like to add a navigation property to the complex type generated for a table-valued UDF, using the (int) value of one of its columns.

After a couple of hours tearing my hair out over this, I'm starting to believe that this is either simply not possible, or the way to do it is so convoluted it's not worth the hassle.

Is it supported at all?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a model of both that tabled-valued UDF and the EF class you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The complex type is auto-generated from the database. So is the entity representing the table that I would like to have a navigation property for. Feel free to make the two models as simple as possible... unless you really want me to post lots of edmx XML?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/efdesign/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support/). There's a section called _Collection of Entity Type_ that might help you.